# Passing a pointer to a C++ function in a C Project

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, extern-c

I have a huge C Project.
And now i needed a C++ function to fill some variables.

With declaring the function as extern "C", it was no problem, to call the function from the C Project.

The Problem is, that i need to pass a pointer to the C++ function, and in the function, i want to assign a value to the pointer.
But exactly at this point, the program crashes with an "Segmentation fault".

Is there a way to make this work? Or is it impossible to work with pointers in this way between C and C++?

---

**Calling the function as thread in C:**

```
 Restwo = pthread_create(&num, NULL, (void *) function, &var);
```

**Header**

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{  // Dies sorgt dafür, dass der Header sowohl in C als auch in C++ funktioniert
#endif

    int function(int *pITS);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**C++ Function**

```
extern "C" {
    int getNewLsaSignals(int *var) {
        printf("Successfully started\n"); //works
        var = 19; //doesn't work
        //insert some c++ code here
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need to be certain that you are actually allocating memory for `var`.

Comment: In reality the variable is a complex struct, which is already filled with data. In the extern C++ function i just want to change these values. So there is already memory allocated for var.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *i want to assign a value to the pointer.*

In that case, you need to change

```
 var = 19;
```

to

```
 *var = 19;
```

because, most likely, `var = 19;` makes the pointer to point to memory location that is inaccessible from your application, so any subsequent de-reference of that pointer will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, it's almost always safe to check the `NULL`ity of the incoming pointer before directly de-referencing it.

Comment: @IlDivinCodino OK, good, then. As a non-native English speaker, sometimes I have trouble understanding other dialects.

Comment: At first thanks for the answer, but If i use *var = 19; the compiler says: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’.

If I code the same example like above in C code var = 19; works perfectly. But i need to do this in C++, and there it throes segmantation fail.

Comment: It does not work perfectly in C, either. It just compiles. It will bomb at run-time. Assigning a literal to a pointer is almost always a mistake.